# How to obtain feature importance with the testing data in R?

Tags: r

I am working with the model random forest in `R`, because I read it has an option to show feature importance. I test the following code:

```
library(randomForest)
mod<-randomForest(PosDesertor ~ ., data=tabla_train, importance=TRUE, 
localImp=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)

result<-predict(mod,tabla_test)
locImp = mod$localImportance
dim(locImp)
vars<-t(locImp)
head(vars,n=10)
```

but it shows the feature importance of the model, with the training data, and not with the test data. It´s easy to see that if we use a testing dataset with less rows than the training set.

My question is:
How can I obtain the same matrix of feature importance but with the testing dataset?
Or there is another option to achieve that?

Comment: The model was fit with the training data so model importance is a property of the training data. What does "model importance" mean to you exactly for the testing data? Is there some sort of formula you would use to calculate it? Not sure how you want to interpret such a value or what it would even mean. Maybe you should be asking for statistics help at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: If you are using the testing data to extract the feature importance then it is not a testing data anymore isn't it? You are treating the testing data also like a training data.

Comment: The goal is to give the prediction on the testing data with aditional information, like adding to the user in each prediction the importance of the features... A 70%, B 40% something like that...

Comment: I have used also the model rulesCBA to obtain the rules that give the prediction answer, to increase the interpretability of the model, but I want something more... to obtain the contribution of each feature to the final answer in each instance of the testing data... like the matrix we obtain for the training data using random forest.

Comment: I think explainVis from the package ExplainPrediction can help me. How can I use this function to show the feature importance of testing data?